# Übersetzung von „Corporatocracy“ als politischer Begriff?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Ich suche die deutsche Entsprechung von *Corporatocracy*. Aber nicht im Sinne einer engen Verflechtung von Wirtschaft und Politik sondern als politisches System. Eine Art „unternehmerische Technokratie“ oder so ähnlich.

Ich vermute, dass es noch keinen etablierten Begriff gibt. Daher akzeptiere ich auch Neuschöpfungen mit griechischer oder lateinischer Herleitung.

Comment: »Herrschaft der Großkonzerne« u. dgl. wird von linken Gruppen gerne verwendet … je linkser desto häufiger.

Comment: Wobei "Herrschaft" hier auch suggerieren kann/soll, daß sie parallel zum existierenden polit. System wirken.

Answer (score 9):

Da das Wort *corporatocracy* selbst auf den englischen Varianten eines lateinischen *(corporatio)* und griechischen Wortes *(krátos, κράτος)* beruht, liegt es nahe deren deutschen Varianten zu benutzen, womit wir bei ***Korporatokratie*** oder ***Korpokratie*** wären.

Alternativ kann man Synonyme für *Konzern* und die für Regierungsformen üblichen Endungen *-kratie, -archie* und *-herrschaft* kombinieren, z. B.:

- ***Korporarchie*** oder ***Korporatarchie***
- ***Konzernokratie*** oder ***Concernokratie*** (wenn es etwas lateinischer bzw. griechischer wirken soll – *Konzern* wurde bis 1901 überwiegend *Concern* geschrieben)
- ***Konzernherrschaft***
- ***Unternehmensherrschaft***

Comment: Ich würde in die Überlegung mit einbeziehen, ob das jemand verstehen soll, ohne dass man noch erklären muss. Sonst würde ich Konzernherrschaft favorisieren.

Comment: @harper: Ich denke, dass in geeignetem Kontext und bei einem mäßig intelligenten und gebildeten Publikum (das diese Wörter zerlegen und ihre Bestandteile zuordnen kann) alle der obigen Begriffe keiner zusätzlichen Erklärung bedürfen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ich halte mich durchaus für "mäßig intelligent und gebildet", aber bei den beiden "Korpo*"-Varianten käme ich ohne Kontext nicht auf die Idee, dass hier auf die (englische, aber IMHO nicht deutsche) Bedeutung "Kapitalgesellschaft" für "K/Corporation" referenziert wird. Im schlimmsten Fall würde ich im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Korporation) nachschlagen und dann "Herrschaft der Burschenschaften" als Bedeutung vermuten. - Trotzdem +1 für "Konzernokratie". Es erhält das Konstruktionsprinzip des Originals und bleibt dabei verständlich. Nur "schön" finde ich es nicht.

Comment: Ich kann Matthias nur zustimmen. Corporation ist in English ein Wort was jeder versteht. Im Deutschen hingegen wissen eher wenige was damit anzufangen. Die Standardwörter ist Unternehmen oder Konzern. Aber Konzernokratie ist super. Wurde auch in einem ROman schon mal benutzt (siehe Wikipedialiste der Herrschaftsformen)   http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Herrschaftsformen